# Incompatible library version: libgdal.dylib requires version 10.0.0 or later, but libgeos_c.1.dylib provides version 9.0.0

Tags: django, gdal

An error appears when I try to run this command:

```
from django.contrib.gis import goal
```

The error is:

> Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.dylib Reason: Incompatible
>   library version: libgdal.dylib requires version 10.0.0 or later, but
>   libgeos_c.1.dylib provides version 9.0.0

I am using Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11)

Comment: How did you install GDAL?  If you didn't build from source, then you should make sure to install the binaries from the same distribution to make sure they were hopefully compiled together.  Here is where the GDAL site recommends getting a Mac installer http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks.

Comment: Removed personal comments and improved grammar

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by using brew to uninstall and install geos, geoip and gdal.

```
brew uninstall geos gdal geoip
brew cleanup
brew install geos
brew install gdal geoip
brew cleanup
```